# Use ksoap to access webservice

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I have little problem to find some information about SOAP web service.
I have a link for my web service:
http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl

And now my problem is how to find NAMESPACE, SOAP_ACTION, METHOD_NAME and URL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial explain well where to find the namespace, soap_action, method_name and url:
http://www.nascenia.com/consuming-soap-web-services-from-android/

Also from [this blog](http://cammykamal.blogspot.fr/2015/04/making-soap-web-service-call-in-android.html):

> SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME (always)
>
> URL will be your webservice url.